# ReactJS manipulating large array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, reactjs

I am relatively new to ReactJS and web scene so I am turning to you, SO.

Our app is working with Firebase to store data. Recently I created a little stress test for our app which is loading about 14k entries from database and saving all of it in array. To be exact, we are downloading some data that we will use to represent different kind of charts and display some statistics about them. 14k, number of entries, is here just to test the speed of everything, we are actually not expecting that many entries per customer (at least not yet). Anyway I decided to think about future and how I should handle this kind of problems.

I did some rough calculations about loading times:
4-6s from Firebase into array
3-4s generating dates for chart and checking for matching dates (fetched data with generated dates) and calculating data

Everything, from saving results from database on is done using array.map. I have also tried using while / for, since I read some articles that .map is not very good when it comes to performance. The result was the same.

So what am I asking here is what kind of "system" should I use if I want to be prepared for "larger" amount of data in arrays? Can .map handle that much data? What are the best practices?

Comment: What actions are performed on array within `.map()` callback? What issues are you having using `.map()`? What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 Everything works ok with .map. I am just going through all results and picking the ones that match certain conditions or counting them.
I am just wondering if there are any best practices regarding this.

Comment: If you are not encountering any issues using `.map()` not sure what answer is expected; where requirement is met using `.map()`? Difficult to determine what "best practices" are where there is no issue at current approach, and alternative approaches mentioned at Question are `while` and `for` loop where "result was the same"?

Comment: A possible alternative to using `.map()`, `while`, `for` loops would be to utilize `ReadableStream` to read the and process the incoming data as as a stream.